# Matplotlib how to divide an histogram by a constant number

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, histogram, normalization

I would like to perform a personalized normalization on histograms on matplotlib. In particular I have two histograms and I would like to divide each of them by a given number (number of generated events).

I don't want to "normally" normalize it, because the "normal normalization" makes the area equal to 1. What I wish for is basically to divide the value of each bin by a given number N, so that if my histogram has 2 bins, one with 5 entries and one with 3, the resulting "normalized" (or "divided") histogram would have the first bin with 5/N entries and the second one with 3/N.

I searched far&wide and found nothing really helpful. Do you have any handy solution? This is my code, working with pandas:

```
num_bins = 128
list_1 = dataframe_1['E']
list_2 = dataframe_2['E']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('Proton energy [MeV]')
ax.set_ylabel('Normalized frequency')
ax.set_title('Proton energy distribution')
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(list_1, num_bins, density=1, alpha=0.5, color='red', ec='red', label='label_1')
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(list_2, num_bins, density=1, alpha=0.5, color='blue', ec='blue', label='label_2')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', fontsize='x-large')
fig.savefig('NiceTitle.pdf')
plt.close('all')
```

Comment: You mean to normalize it?

Comment: There is a keyword `normed=None`

Comment: Or you might be able to use the keyword `weights`...

Comment: I don't want to "normally" normalize it, because the "normal normalization" makes the area equal to 1. What I wish for is basically to divide the value of each bin by a given number N, so that if my histo has 2 bins, one with 5 entries and one with 3, the resulting "normalized" (or "divided") histogram would have the first bin with 5/N entries and the second one with 3/N.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a hack to get images like this https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended_06.hires.png ?